# Mqtt isConnected property is false but messages are received

Tags: c#, mqtt, mosquitto, mqttnet

I'm trying to connect to Mosquitto using MQTTnet. I am able to receive messages but `IsConnected` property is `false`. Anyone know why?
Only property `iStart` is set to `true`.
The problem seems to be with the Mosquitto host.

`mosquitto.conf` is mostly defaults. I only have these parameters set:

```
allow_anonymous true
password_file C:\mosquitto\passwd
tls_version tlsv1.2
log_dest file C:\mosquitto\log\mosquitto.log
```

Log file is empty.

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var mqttClientId = "MyClientId";             // Unique ClientId or pass a GUID as string for something random
            var mqttBrokerAddress = "localhost";         // hostname or IP address of your MQTT broker
            var mqttBrokerUsername = "guest";       // Broker Auth username if using auth
            var mqttBrokerPassword = "guest";       // Broker Auth password if using auth
            var topic = "topic";                 // topic to subscribe to
            var mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();
            var mqttClientOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                        .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                        .WithClientOptions(new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                            .WithTcpServer(mqttBrokerAddress, 1883)
                            .WithCredentials(mqttBrokerUsername, mqttBrokerPassword)    // Remove this line if no auth
                            .WithCleanSession().WithKeepAlivePeriod(new TimeSpan(1))//.WithTls(tlsOptions)
                            .Build()
                        )
                        .Build();

            mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += async e => MqttOnNewMessage(e);
            mqttClient.ConnectedAsync += async e => MqttOnConnected(e);
            mqttClient.DisconnectedAsync += async e => MqttOnDisconnected(e);
            mqttClient.SynchronizingSubscriptionsFailedAsync += async e => test(e);
            mqttClient.ConnectingFailedAsync += async e => test2(e);
            var aaa = new List<MqttTopicFilter>();
            var bbb = new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic(topic).Build();
            aaa.Add(bbb);
            try
            {
                await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(aaa);
                await mqttClient.StartAsync(mqttClientOptions);
                System.Console.WriteLine(mqttClient.IsConnected); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void test2(ConnectingFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void test(ManagedProcessFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void MqttOnNewMessage(MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do something with each incoming message from the topic

            Console.WriteLine($"MQTT Client: OnNewMessage Topic: {e.ApplicationMessage.Topic} / Message: {e.ApplicationMessage.Payload}");
        }

        private static void MqttOnConnected(MqttClientConnectedEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine($"MQTT Client: Connected with result: {e.ConnectResult.ResultCode}");

        private static void MqttOnDisconnected(MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine($"MQTT Client: Broker connection lost with reason: {e.Reason}.");
    }
```

Comment: The code shown does not appear to access `IsConnected`, please show where/how you are reading this. What problem is this causing (you say you can receive messages; what else is not working?). Increasing the Mosquitto log level (e.g. `log_type all`) might provide information that helps you trace your issue (e.g. if the client is disconnecting).

Comment: I added the line System.Console.WriteLine (mqttClient.IsConnected); which returns false. Everything works fine but status is bad. I tried to connect to test.mosquitto.org and the IsConnected status is true there. No errors in ConnectingFailedAsync.

Comment: [StartAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/6fdee9e0db738817c6f457c3597f84460cff3cd0/Source/MQTTnet.Extensions.ManagedClient/ManagedMqttClient.cs#L217) starts a thread (that manages the connection) and then returns. The connection will come up later; move your `WriteLine` to `MqttOnConnected`.

Answer (score 0):

it seams like the problem is something to do with the keep alive attribute on MQTTNet.
For me it got fix by setting the

> .WithKeepAlivePeriod(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))

attribute on my

> MqttClientOptionBuilder()

with a timespan of 60 sek

That is what i could gather for a Issue for MqttNet github:
https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/issues/1290#issuecomment-968064210